# Where are the form settings of the Swing Application Framework stored?

Tags: java, swing

I want to delete them, because for some reason my forms are restored to the wrong dimensions on startup.

I didn't find anything in my user directory, but I'm not event sure what to look for.

I'm interested about Windows and Linux.

Comment: did you use an IDE to create it?  If so which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://appframework.dev.java.net/nonav/javadoc/AppFramework-1.03/index.html):

> Session state is stored locally,
>   relative to the user's home directory,
>   by the LocalStorage  save and load 
>   methods. The startup method must set
>   the ApplicationContext vendorId and
>   applicationId properties to ensure
>   that the correct local directory is
>   selected on all platforms. For
>   example, on Windows XP, the full
>   pathname for filename "session.xml" is
>   typically:
>
> ${userHome}\Application
>   Data\${vendorId}\${applicationId}\session.xml
>
> Where the value of ${userHome} is the
>   the value of the Java System property
>   "user.home". On Solaris or Linux the
>   file is:
>
> ${userHome}/.${applicationId}/session.xml
>
> and on OSX:
>
> ${userHome}/Library/Application
>   Support/${applicationId}/session.xml